# Ethernet communication: Sending data via ethernet to an RTL IP

Tags: ethernet, protocol, vivado, tcp-ip, xilinx-sdk

I have established Ethernet TCP/IP 100 MHz using Microblaze on my Arty A7 100T FPGA board.

Then I connected the interconnect to an AXI_GPIO, and set the GPIO config as let_4bits. Then I made the port external, and a MASTER port is generated. So, I was able to toggle my LED via commands sent via Ethernet.

I have Verilog code I wrote which is a transmitter (RTL), and I want to connect it to my Ethernet system to send data to the transmitter via an Ethernet user interface (I am using Hercules).

[image]

[image]

Should I make the RTL IP as custom AXI IP? Or can I use AXI_GPIO to do the read and write?

What is the difference between these 2 ports?

[image]

I don't mean channel 1 or 2, but whether you connect the port before expanding it, or after expanding it. They are different! I can't connect the port before expanding it to a normal external port such as button or LED; it has to be expanded as in the photo in channel 2.